# Phonegap Use Intent / WebIntent to pick file

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Please I am looking to use intent/webintent to open an app that can be used as a file browser/explorer for selecting audio files.

The URL(fullpath) for selected item would then be passed as source for in app media.play().

Any samples would be welcome.

Thanks.

Ismael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check my plugin for Phonegap, which as I believe can do what you need.

https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener

All you gotta do is to pass a variable with the local path of the file:

window.plugins.fileOpener.open("file:///mnt.sdcard/Android/data/com.example.app")

You would only need to correct FileOpener.java file, so it matches file types you want to handle, for example mp3, wav etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marek would have a look at this.